# MoonMail: Tracking clicks per email

Tags: moonmail

I'm looking to extract a list of email addresses belonging to users who clicked a specific link in a [MoonMail](https://moonmail.io) email campaign. Is this possible? The documentation only states there's an `incrementClickCount` function, but doesn't describe individual tracking or filtering.
The same happens with opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `saveClicks` stores the information about a link click in `Clicks` DynamoDB table. It contains `campaignId`, `linkId` and `recipientId` (which is the Base64 representation of the email)